# Python How to plot "grouped by" scatter on (mean of column vs percentile)

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, scatter-plot

I have the following dataframe `df_male`:

[image]

And I used groupby() to see mean value of `gagne_sum_t` column on each `risk_percentile`, `df_male.groupby(["risk_percentile","race"]).aggregate(np.mean)`:

[image]

I want to scatterplot this `gagne_sum_t vs risk_percentile` grouped by `race`, for something like:
[image]

With this legend for the plot:
[image]

However, I am not too sure how to proceed from here... How do I use `groupby()` again from here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do `group_by` again. You can start plotting from the grouped dataframe. You already have this:

```
plot_df = df_male.groupby(["risk_percentile","race"]).aggregate(np.mean)
```

If you have pyplot (typically imported as `plt`) then  you can plot straight from that dataframe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x=plot_df.gagne_sum_t, y=plot_df.index.names[0], c=plot_df.race)
ax.legend() 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, but ```plot_df.risk_percentile``` does not exist because ```plot_df``` only has 4 columns without ```risk_percentile``` as a column. It is just a grouping factor for ```plot_df```...

Comment: Oh, then it's an index. Let me adjust my answer.

Comment: Since you've created a group by, it's using a multi-index. You can get the values by calling the list `df.index.names` and by indexing the first one so it looks like `df.index.names[0]`